# Java Snake Eyes Program Error

Tags: java, loops, random

I'm making a simulator to see how many times the random number generator takes to "roll" snake eyes.  The program just repeats

```
Not snake eyes yet :(
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SnakeEyes {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random myRandom = new Random();
    int die1 = 0, tries = 0, die2 = 0;

    System.out.println("Welcome to SEO (Snake Eyes Operator)!");
    System.out.println("How many rolls will it take you to get to snake eyes! ");

    die1 = myRandom.nextInt(6) + 1;
    die2 = myRandom.nextInt(6) + 1;

    while (die1 + die2 != 2) {
        System.out.println("Not snake eyes yet :( ");
        tries = +1;

    }

    System.out.print("You have rolled snake eyes! ");
    System.out.print("Congratulations!  It only took you ");
    System.out.print(tries);
    System.out.print("!");

}

}
```

I believe it is a problem with an open loop but I'm not sure.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use while loop, you must update the value you check or the loop will never stop.

You need to update `die1` and `die2` values inside the loop.

Comment: i have added the die1 = and the die2 = into the while loop (copy paste after system.outprint.ln in the while loop) and updated the tries = +1 to tries += 1.  It still gives me the infinite loop.

Comment: You can add some prints to debug it yourself. How about print the values of die1 and die2 inside the loop?

Answer (score 2):

Once this `while (die1 + die2 != 2)` condition get failed it will go to infinite loop and there must be a condition to break the loop.
try this (will break loop after 10 iterations):

```
while (die1 + die2 != 2) {      
    System.out.println("Not snake eyes yet :( ");
    die1 = myRandom.nextInt(6) + 1;
    die2 = myRandom.nextInt(6) + 1;
    tries += 1;
    if(tries==10)
        break;
}
```

and replace `tries = +1;` with `tries += 1;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `myRandom.nextInt(6) + 1;` **inside** the `while` loop, otherwise it will iterate by checking the same values over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

```
die1 + die2
```

is not changing and hence the loop will run for ever if the following condition is met :

```
while (die1 + die2 != 2)
```

So you may have to put a logic in your while loop to logically update the values of `die1` and/or `die2` .